# cygwin exception stackdumpfile error?

Tags: c++

I have made a function that is supposed to add two numbers in a given base represented as strings together. The reverse string method referenced reverses a string and works correctly.  However, whenever I try to call this method, I receive the following error. 
 0 [main] proj02 7364 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to proj02.exe.stackdump
Any ideas as to what is causing this error and how I could fix it?

```
const string the_chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string add_string_nums(string num1, string num2, long base)
{
    string added_num="";
    long len1 = num1.length(), len2 = num2.length(), extra = 0, temp;
    num1 = reverse_str(num1);
    num2 = reverse_str(num2);
while (len1 > len2)
    num2 += "0";
while (len2 > len1)
    num1 += "0";
num1 = reverse_str(num1);
num2 = reverse_str(num2);
for (int i = 1; i <= num1.length(); i ++)
{
   temp = the_chars.find(num2[num2.length() - i]) + the_chars.find(num2[num2.length()-i]) + extra;
   extra = 0;
   if (temp > base)
   {
       extra = 1;
       temp = temp - base;
   }
   added_num += the_chars.at(temp);
    } 
    return added_num;
}
int main() {
  string s = add_string_nums("1", "12", 10);
   cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is here:

```
while (len1 > len2)
    num2 += "0";
while (len2 > len1)
    num1 += "0";
```

`len1` and `len2` are cached values and never change as the strings grow in size. Unless both strings are the same size, one loop will spin until the string it's modifying gets so big that the computer runs out of storage.

Solution (also removes the need to reverse the strings):

```
while (len1 > num2.length())
    num2 = "0" + num2;
while (len2 > num1.length())
    num1 = "0" + num1;
```

Couple other problems in there, but you shouldn't have any trouble finding them [with a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).